# Exception thrown with Two Dimensional Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to have an Object with a two dimensional array in it. it will hold questions with associated choices and the correct answer. The first time thru it works correctly but the second time with i= 1 k= 0 I get an exception. Here is the relevant code with the exception thrown after the first entry in the object:

```
var testquestions = [{
        question:[],
        choices:[[]],
        answer:[],
       }
      ];
      var i = 0;

 $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
          $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
          $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
            minWidth: 700,
            minHeight: 650,
            buttons: [
                 {
                   text: "Add Question",
                   click: function() {
                       i = testquestions[0].question.length;
                       testquestions[0].question[i] = $( "#question" ).val();
                       for(var k = 0; k < 4; k++){
                           if ($("#" + k).val() != "")  {
                             alert("i and k values are " + i + "nd " + k);
                             testquestions[0].choices[i][k] = $( "#" + k ).val();
                           }
                        }  // for k
                      testquestions[0].answer[i] = $("#correctAnswer").val();
                      $("#test")[0].reset();
                      alert(testquestions[0].question[i]);
                    }
                 }
```

exception

```
TypeError: testquestions[0].choices[i] is undefined

testquestions[0].choices[i][k] = $( "#" + k ).val();
```

Can someone tell me if I am declaring and invoking the 2-d array correctly? The exception gets thrown when i = 1. Thanks
Update: Answer below did solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`testquestions[0].choices[i]` is not defined (because of `choices:[[]]`) and never assigned, so you can't access it with `[k]`. Add a

```
testquestions[0].choices[i] = [];
```

right below the

```
testquestions[0].question[i] = $( "#question" ).val();
```

to fix that.

Notes:

- `var foo = { choices:[[]] }` is equivalent to

  ```
  var foo = {};
  foo.choices = [];
  foo.choices[0] = [];
  ```

  It initializes the `choices` field to be an array with one element: an empty array. So, `.choices[0]` exists, but `choices[1]` does not, which causes the error on `choices[1][k]`.
- Tou might want to use `console.log()` (press F12 to see it) instead of `alert()`, as that gets annoying inside loops. ;-)
- It's best not to use `#1`. See [the note on this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id): have an `id` always start with a letter.
- Since a question always has some (4) options, perhaps you could use this structure: `{ question: "?", choices: ["A","B","C"], answer: "C" }`

  ```
  var testquestions = [];

  function addQuestion( q, c, a ) {
      testquestions.push( { question: q, choices: c, answer: a } );
  }
  ```

  and your handler:

  ```
   click: function() {
              addQuestion( 
                  $( "#question" ).val(),
                  $( 'input.choice' ).map( function(i,e){ return $(e).val();}).get(),
                  $("#correctAnswer").val()
              );

              $("#test")[0].reset();
            }
  ```

  you would need to change the `<input id='1'>` ... `<input id='4'>` to `<input class='choice'>`.

**update**

```js
var testquestions = [{
        question:[],
        choices:[],
        answer:[],
       }
      ];
      var i = 0;

$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
   i = testquestions[0].question.length;
   testquestions[0].question[i] = $( "#question" ).val();
   testquestions[0].choices[i] = [];
   for(var k = 0; k < 4; k++){
     if ($("#c" + k).val() != "")  {
       testquestions[0].choices[i][k] = $( "#c" + k ).val();
     }
   }  // for k
   testquestions[0].answer[i] = $("#correctAnswer").val();
   console.log("Added question", testquestions[0] );
   $("#test")[0].reset();                      
 }
);
```

```css
fieldset { display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='dialog'>
  <form id='test'>
    Q <input id='question'/><br/>
    A <input id='correctAnswer'/><br/>
    C <fieldset label='foo' title='bar'>
    <input id='c0' class='choice'/><br/>
    <input id='c1' class='choice'/><br/>
    <input id='c2' class='choice'/><br/>
    <input id='c3' class='choice'/><br/>
    </fieldset>
    <button id='opener'>add question</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Works now. Did I not declare the 2-d array correctly? I declared choices[[]] I thought would create an empty choices 2-d array that could be referenced with nothing further. if you could expand much appreciated

Comment: I added a note on that. It partially works. It does initialize `choices[0]` with the array `[]`, but not `choices[1]`. You'd need to write `choices: [ [], [] ]`, but you won't know how many you need in advance, so it's best to allocate the array in the click handler and simply write `choices: []`. I also suggested a slightly different approach. (If that jQuery map is over your head, all it does is create an array populated with the values of `#1` etc; i wanted to keep the code short).

Comment: Damn. You did more in 5 mins then I have in two days:) Thanks for elucidating the answer as I will be coming back to it as a reference.

Comment: JS is a struggle at first, but it gets easier ;)

Comment: Still have one problem. I put in line console.log(testquestions[0].question[i] + testquestions[0].choices[i][k] + testquestions[0].answer[i]); after testquestions[0].answer[i] = $("#correctAnswer").val(); line and all the choices items show as undefined in console. Any thoughts.

Comment: That's because `testquestions[0].choices[i][k]` is `undefined`, because `k=4`. This happened when `for (k=0; k<4; k++)` broke out of the loop because `k<4` no longer was true. You effectively do `answer + undefined + correctanswer` which is undefined. I added a (slightly modified) snippet based on your code where I `console.log( testanswers[0] )` - this allows you to inspect it in the DOM tree. It's better to use `,` in console.log than `+`, for this reason.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but I noticed in firebug that when I tried to inspect testquestions contents when I clicked on it you can usually see the object contents but this time after the first go thru the loop I get nothing when I click on it. Also when I tried something like testquestions.choices[2][3] to print to console before reset command it came up as undefined. and yet I knew I had put in several questions. so youre saying testquestions object is there and holding the values?

Comment: Yes. If you run my snippet, it `console.log()`s it. You can then click on it. I did find that FireFox doesn't refresh the contents, so, after you click the 'add question' button, you have to click the last log entry again to re-open the DOM panel. The next thing I noticed is that the 'summary' of the folded (`+`) items does not match what's inside them. Click the `+` and you'll see it's all there. It's a refreshing issue. If you want you could add `alert( JSON.stringify( testquestions ) )` to be really sure. Consider my suggestion: `testquestions[ 1 ].choices[2]` is much easier access.